# Shrink NTFS partition without Windows installed?

Tags: windows, partitioning

I have damaged Windows 8.1 partition and I can't boot it up. I would like to shrink the partition and install Windows 10 alongside it. Can I do it without working windows? I have Linux Mint installed also, but I'm afraid of dealing with NTFS partitions on Linux.

Answer (score 1):

GParted on Linux should be fine.

Other than that, Hiren's Boot CD has several programs that can do this.
[Hiren's Boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/)

You can put Hiren's Boot CD on a USB using Unetbootin on Linux Mint and then boot to the Mini Windows XP on it to use the partition tools.

You'd probably be best off recovering any data from the 8.1 partition using your Linux Mint install, if at all possible and either removing the partition entirely or reinstalling 8.1 on it. No point in having a damaged , useless partition taking up space on your hard drive.